# eOS 6 - How to delete Calculator, Tasks, and Web?

Tags: release-odin

Using the Uninstall option in the app list context menu gives errors such as

> Application state not set as installed in AppCenter for package:
> Calculator

I've also tried `apt purge` for `pantheon-calculator`, `calculus`, and `epiphany-browser` none of which worked. Have the package names changed? How is the intended way to delete these apps if there's any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove them with

flatpak remove io.elementary.camera io.elementary.calculator org.gnome.Epiphany

I don't know why these applications do not show as installed in the appcenter. This might be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to remove through AppCenter?

Comment: They are not listed in the installed tab of the AppCenter. Installing them again through AppCenter does not resolve the situation.